# Run String of VBA within AHK

Tags: excel, vba, autohotkey

I am creating an AHK script to manipulate an excel spreadsheet which necessitates the use of VBA. I know how to use single lines of VBA within AHK by converting them to COM calls (like `Xl.Worksheets(1).ShowAllData`), but what I need to do now is run a series of commands.

```
Worksheets(1).ShowAllData
With Intersect(Columns("G"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
 .Replace "0*", "#N/A", xlPart
 .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

I tried simply placing Xl (my COM object handle) in front of various sections of this code, and it didn't help. Like this:

```
#j::
 Xl.Worksheets(1).ShowAllData
 Xl.With Intersect(Columns("G"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
  Xl.Replace "0*", "#N/A", xlPart
  Xl.SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
 Xl.End With
Return
```

AHK seems to have troubles with more complicated VBA commands. For instance, I can create a new sheet, with `Xl.Worksheets.Add`, but if I try to add a sheet and name it, like this: `Xl.Worksheets.Add().Name = "MySheet"` it freaks out.

What am I missing?
Thanks!!
Paul

Comment: Constants like `xlPart` are defined in VBA but likely not in your calling environment: you can substitute the actual values instead (which you can find in the VBEditor Object Browser in Excel).  It would help to update your question to show the code you actually tried.

Comment: I looked in the VBA Editor and couldn't find the actual values, so I must simply be missing them (I'm newer to VBA than I am AHK). I updated my question with my actual code, though it's not very different. Thanks @Tim!

Comment: In the VBE, open the *Immediate* window (Ctrl+G) and type `?xlpart` then hit enter. If the associated references are included in the project (xlPart should be in one of the defaults) you will get the numerical equivalent.

Comment: Here is a list of all [Excel enumerated constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221100%28v=office.11%29.aspx).  They are listed in alphabetical order of use, so using the code you've provided, expand the section named "XlCellType" and you'll see that `xlCellTypeConstants = 2`.  In the XlSpecialCellsValue you'll find `xlErrors = 16`.

Comment: As a side note, you have used `xlConstants` instead of `xlCellTypeConstants`.  `xlConstants` doesn't exist an enumerated value, and that may be causing the problem.  Either way, using the actual value instead of the enumerated constant is recommended

Comment: Back from the weekend! Ok, so I'm still stuck on this one. It seems like the AHK encoder (or whatever it's called) isn't recognizing a lot of VBA code. Is it possible that there are only a limited number of VBA commands that can be run through AHK?

Answer (score 0):

`With` is a compiling statement. Using it or not using it doesn't change what your program does, though using it makes it a bit faster.

```
Intersect(Columns("G"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Replace "0*", "#N/A", xlPart
Intersect(Columns("G"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
```

Above is same code as yours without using `With`.

Saying you are missing the constants is a stupid thing to say. You do not get a special version of Excel different to everyone else. Cause they are there. Use **SEARCH** in Object Browser.

PS: `With` is part of VBA. Everything else you are doing has nothing to do with VBA but with Excel's Object. The two are quite separate. You are NOT writing VBA code but using Excel via COM in your language. VBA has nothing to do with it which is why `with` won't work.

Comment: Ahh, ok, your "PS" about VBA and Excel COM makes total sense! Thanks!
But AHK is still balking, even with your code (which worked swimmingly in Excel). Here's the error it gave me:
"Error: Call to nonexistent function. Specifically: Columns("G"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Replace "0*", "#N/A", xlPart"
I copied your code exactly, and simply appended it with "Xl."